# VSCode - HTML Include extension

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Is there any VSCode extension to include HTML code during development? something like this:

```
   <body>
     <!-- @import "components/header.html" -->
     <main>
       <p>Hello world.</p>
     </main>
     <!-- @import "components/footer.html" -->
   </body>
```

Comment: write your own snippets for this, also look at Emmet (see VSC doc)

Comment: @rioV8  I think you do not understand. How can I includ html code from file into another html file with snippet?

Comment: looks like a template language, is this standard HTML